# Game Center in iOS: GKScore vs. GKAchievement?

Tags: c#, ios, game-center, game-center-leaderboard, gkscore

I have a question about a topic related to "Game Center" in iOS:  **GKAchievement** vs. **GKScore** ?

(1)  **GKAchievement**

I know that in iOS Game Center, we can define the achievements and leaderboards and specify, for example, that when gamers complete the first achievement then we give gamers 10 points. That is when we use **GKAchievement** to submit an achievement to game center upon users successfully complete an achievement.

(2)  **GKScore**

So, when do we need to use  **GKScore** ? As I mention in the previous paragraph, we can give gamers a specific score when gamers complete the first achievement. Then, do we still need to use  **GKScore** if we already use **GKAchievement** to give users new scores per new achievements ? What is the purpose of **GKScore** ?

Or perhaps, when we use **GKScore**, we don't need to use **GKAchievement** ? In other words, we only need to use 1 of these 2 classes and not both ?

---

Here is the typical code in C# to submit score **GKScore**:

```
    public void reportScore(long score, string category, GameCenterController controller, bool show_dialog)
    {
        GKScore scoreReporter = new GKScore (category);
        scoreReporter.Value = score;

        scoreReporter.ReportScore ((error) => {     
        ((error) => {   // original
            if(error == null){
                if(show_dialog){
                    new UIAlertView ("Score Reported to Game Center", "Score Reported Successfully", null, "OK", null).Show ();
                }
            }
            else{
                if(show_dialog){
                    new UIAlertView ("Can't Submit Score to Game Center", "Please make sure that you logon to Game Center", null, "OK", null).Show ();
                }
            }

            //NSThread.SleepFor(1);         
            controller.updateHighScore();   

        });
    }
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some testing and kind of figured out the "***answer***" myself.

If we use both **GKAchievement** and **GKScore** to submit both achievements and scores, then the score submitted via **GKScore** will be displayed in the Global Leaderboards. This score will overwrite the score that is supposed to be displayed when we submit achievements via **GKAchievement**

***Here are my 2 test cases:***

**(A) Test Case 1:**

Suppose that I define an achievement that is worth **100** points in Game Center. When users play the game and complete this achievement, I first submit this achievement and then submit the score of **3456** points (via my code for testing purpose).

Next, I open the Game Center, and I can see that my score displayed on the Leaderboard is **3456** (and NOT **100** points).

**(B) Test Case 2:**

Suppose that I define an achievement that is worth **100** points. When users play the game and complete this achievement, I only submit this achievement and then do **NOT** manually submit the score of **3456** points (via my code for testing purpose).

Next, I open the Game Center, and I can see that my score displayed on the Leaderboard is exactly **100**.

---

***NOTE*:  This following behavior happens only if developers set the "Score Submission Type" to "Best Score"**.

If you subsequently use GKScore to submit a score that is **HIGHER** than the existing score in the Leaderboard in Game Center, then this new **HIGHER**  score will be automatically posted in the Leaderboard (by Apple Game Center and we don't have to do any thing else).

Now, if you subsequently use GKScore to submit a score that is **LOWER** than the existing score in the Leaderboard in Game Center, then this new **LOWER** score will **NOT** be posted in the Leaderboard.

---

(On the other hand, if if developers set the "Score Submission Type" to "Most Recent Score", then only the "Most Recent Score" and **NOT** the Highest score is posted on Game Center.)